# How to download file from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets with Google API and authentification / service account?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I want to automatically download a file on a daily basis from a `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets` account (service account).

I have a cred.json file with:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "id_1234",
  "private_key_id": "12345678901234567890",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n1234567890\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "id_1234@id_1234.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1234567890",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/id_1234%40id_1234.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

So far I have :

```
import os

import io
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = ".env"

with build(serviceName="drive", version="v3", credentials=os.environ) as service:
    ???
```

I can't find a complete example in the Google API docs for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can build simple parser with gspread lib

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread as gs

gc = gs.service_account(filename = 'cred.json')
sh = gc.open_by_url('place here url to your google sheet file')

ws = sh.worksheet('paste here your sheet name')
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.get_all_records())
df.to_excel('excel_name.xlsx')
```

You can loop trough sheets if you have many of them and eg merge them in to one dataframe, or save it as a separate dataframes.

Remember to share you Google Sheet to generated token as a user

Here you have whole documentation: https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.12.0/

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I would like to do it with the official Google library.

Comment: Gspread is essentially the apotheosis of the Google client implemented in Python when it comes to Google Sheets. Google doesn't have an official "Google Sheets" library, its own documentation uses the generic Google API library, which GSpread abstracts on top of. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Unless you have some objection to httplib2 (in which case you can't use Google's libraries either), it is the de facto official Google library. Google's abstraction layer is very thin https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html